# Neighborhood structure in a uniform hypergraph

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

Consider a $k$-uniform connected hypergraph with vertex set $V$ and hyperedge set $E$, as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph#Symmetric_hypergraphs .

We impose the following condition on this hypergraph: for any vertex $v$, let $T_v$ be set of all hyperedges that are incident on $v$. Then for any two distinct vertices $v,v'$, the sets $T_v, T_{v'}$ are distinct.

Intuition is that if there were two or more vertices that shared same set of incident edges, then we would merge these vertices into one vertex, just to avoid `wasting' vertices.

Two hyperedges are said to be *neighbours* if there is a vertex on which both are incident. My question is, what is the minimum number of neighbours that any hyperedge in this graph must have?

Comment: Great comment! I have edited the question.

Comment: I am confused about your "merge" thing. Let's say $k = 2$, so that we are talking about usual graphs. Then two vertices share the same set of edges if and only if there is no edge from any of them to any of the remaining vertices. Are you sure this is the kind of "waste" that you want to avoid? It doesn't seem natural to me ... or am I missing something?

Comment: That's a good point. Im assuming only connected hypergraph. Let me edit that. Now, in a connected graph (k=2), every vertex has different set of incident edges.